# NLTK word categorizing with POS_TAG

Tags: python, python-2.7, nltk

I have a paragraph of text from which I need to extract `NN`, `NNP` , `NNPS` and `NNS`.

I had a doubt: the result is different if I tokenize with `word_tokenize(paragraph)` as compared to `word_tokenize(sentence in paragraph)`. I create the sentence in paragraph by using `sent_tokenize(paragraph)`.

I would like to know Which approach is better.
The outputs:

sent_tokenize() and then word_tokenize():

```
['BUSINESS', 'Astronics', 'supplier', 'products', 'aerospace', 'defense', 'industries', 'products', 'high-performance', 'lighting', 'systems', 'power', 'generation', 'systems', 'aircraft', 'safety', 'systems', 'power', 'distribution', 'systems', 'aerospace', 'industry', 'test', 'training', 'simulation', 'systems', 'locations', 'United', 'States', 'Canada', 'products', 'subsidiaries', 'Luminescent', 'Systems', 'Inc.', 'Luminescent', 'Systems', 'Canada', 'Inc.', 'DME', 'Corporation', 'Astronics', 'Advanced', 'Electronic', 'Systems', 'Corp.', 'On', 'January', '%', 'stock', 'DME', 'Corporation', 'DME', 'DME', 'provider', 'test', 'training', 'simulation', 'equipment', 'aviation', 'safety', 'equipment', 'airfield', 'systems', 'result', 'acquisition', 'DME', 'January', 'segments', 'Aerospace', 'Test', 'Systems', 'Products', 'Customers', 'Our', 'Aerospace', 'segment', 'designs', 'manufactures', 'products', 'aerospace', 'industry', 'Product', 'lines', 'Aircraft', 'Lighting', 'Cabin', 'Electronics', 'Airframe', 'Power', 'Airfield', 'Lighting', 'Aerospace', 'customers', 'airframe', 'manufacturers', 'OEM', 's', 'aviation', 'markets', 'suppliers', 'OEM', 'aircraft', 'operators', 'airlines', 'branches', 'U.S.', 'Department', 'Defense', 'Federal', 'Aviation', 'Administration', 'airport', 'operators', 'segment', 'sales', '%', 'transport', 'market', '%', 'aircraft', 'market', '%', 'business', 'jet', 'market', '%', 'market', 'segment', 'sales', 'result', 'contracts', 'purchase', 'orders', 'customers', 'basis', 'year', 'procurements', 'contract', 'commitments', 'occasion', 'Company', 'commitments', 'blanket', 'purchase', 'orders', 'customers', 'multiple', 'year', 'deliveries', 'hardware', 'customers', 'Test', 'Systems', 'segment', 'designs', 'develops', 'manufactures', 'maintains', 'communications', 'weapons', 'test', 'systems', 'training', 'simulation', 'devices', 'applications', 'Test', 'Systems', 'segment', 'Astronics', 'products', 'U.S.', 'militaries', 'manufacturers', 'communication', 'systems', 'segment', 'sales', 'markets', 'segment', 'revenue', 'result', 'price', 'contracts', 'percentage', 'completion', 'method', 'multiplying', 'contract', 'value', 'ratio', 'contract', 'costs', 'date', 'contract', 'costs', 'estimates', 'usage', 'percentage-of-completion', 'contract', 'revenues', 'contracts', 'process', 'estimates-to-completion', 'gross', 'profit', 'gross', 'profit', 'contracts', 'process', 'unforeseen', 'events', 'changes', 'circumstances', 'place', 'accounting', 'period', 'gross', 'profit', 'contracts', 'process', 'gross', 'profit', 'completion', 'contracts', 'amounts', 'periods', 'Sales', 'Segment', 'Geographic', 'Region', 'Major', 'Customer', 'Canadian', 'Operations', 'Note', 'Item', 'Statements', 'Supplementary', 'Data', 'report', 'concentration', 'business', 'customers', 'Panasonic', 'Avionics', 'Corporation', 'Department', 'Defense', 'branches', 'U.S.', 'Government', 'Sales', 'Panasonic', 'Avionics', '%', 'sales', '%', 'sales', '%', 'sales', 'Accounts', 'customer', 'December', 'Sales', 'U.S.', 'Government', '%', 'sales', '%', 'sales', '%', 'sales', 'Accounts', 'customer', 'December', 'Contents', 'Strategy', 'Our', 'strategy', 'positions', 'leadership', 'chosen', 'aerospace', 'defense', 'markets', 'positions', 'amount', 'content', 'volume', 'product', 'markets', 'businesses', 'capabilities', 'leadership', 'position', 'direction', 'Practices', 'Maintaining', 'Working', 'Capital', 'Liquidity', 'Part', 'II', 'Item', 'Management', 's', 'Discussion', 'Analysis', 'Financial', 'Condition', 'Results', 'Operations', 'Liquidity', 'section', 'report', 'Conditions', 'competition', 'market', 'sectors', 'respect', 'performance', 'price', 'competitors', 'resources', 'Success', 'markets', 'depends', 'product', 'innovation', 'customer', 'support', 'responsiveness', 'management', 'technologies', 'engineering', 'support', 'markets', 'Government', 'Contracts', 'All', 'U.S.', 'Government', 'contracts', 'subcontracts', 'U.S.', 'Government', 'customer', 'termination', 'election', 'government', 'January', 'acquisition', 'DME', 'revenue', 'stream', 'relies', 'spending', 'portion', 'DME', 's', 'applications', 'Raw', 'Materials', 'Materials', 'supplies', 'components', 'sources', 'loss', 'source', 'operations', 'Seasonality', 'business', 'Backlog', 'December', 'backlog', 'December', 'backlog', 'Backlog', 'Aerospace', 'segment', 'December', 'December', 'backlog', 'Backlog', 'Test', 'Systems', 'segment', 'December', 'Patents', 'number', 'patents', 'aggregate', 'protection', 'patents', 'value', 'material', 'business', 'dependent', 'protection', 'patents', 'cabin', 'power', 'distribution', 'product', 'patents', 'patent', 'applications', 'electroluminescence', 'instrument', 'panels', 'technology', 'patent', 'cabin', 'power', 'distribution', 'technology', 'expertise', 'techniques', 'trade', 'secret', 'laws', 'arrangements', 'rights', 'protection', 'markets', 'Contents', 'Research', 'Development', 'Engineering', 'Activities', 'We', 'variety', 'engineering', 'design', 'activities', 'research', 'development', 'activities', 'improvement', 'application', 'technologies', 'costs', 'cost', 'sales', 'Research', 'development', 'engineering', 'costs']
```

word_tokenize() only:

```
['BUSINESS', 'Astronics', 'supplier', 'products', 'aerospace', 'defense', 'industries.', 'Our', 'products', 'high-performance', 'lighting', 'systems', 'power', 'generation', 'systems', 'aircraft', 'safety', 'systems', 'power', 'distribution', 'systems', 'aerospace', 'industry', 'test', 'training', 'simulation', 'systems', 'military.', 'We', 'locations', 'United', 'States', 'Canada.', 'We', 'products', 'subsidiaries', 'Luminescent', 'Systems', 'Inc.', 'Luminescent', 'Systems', 'Canada', 'Inc.', 'DME', 'Corporation', 'Astronics', 'Advanced', 'Electronic', 'Systems', 'Corp.', 'On', 'January', '%', 'stock', 'DME', 'Corporation', 'DME', 'DME', 'provider', 'test', 'training', 'simulation', 'equipment', 'aviation', 'safety', 'equipment', 'airfield', 'systems.', 'As', 'result', 'acquisition', 'DME', 'January', 'segments', 'Aerospace', 'Test', 'Systems.', 'Products', 'Customers', 'Our', 'Aerospace', 'segment', 'designs', 'manufactures', 'products', 'aerospace', 'industry.', 'Product', 'lines', 'Aircraft', 'Lighting', 'Cabin', 'Electronics', 'Airframe', 'Power', 'Airfield', 'Lighting.', 'Our', 'Aerospace', 'customers', 'airframe', 'manufacturers', 'OEM', 's', 'aviation', 'markets', 'suppliers', 'OEM', 'aircraft', 'operators', 'airlines', 'branches', 'U.S.', 'Department', 'Defense', 'Federal', 'Aviation', 'Administration', 'airport', 'operators.', 'During', 'segment', 'sales', '%', 'transport', 'market', '%', 'aircraft', 'market', '%', 'business', 'jet', 'market', '%', 'market.', 'Most', 'segment', 'sales', 'result', 'contracts', 'purchase', 'orders', 'customers', 'basis', 'year', 'procurements', 'contract', 'commitments.', 'On', 'occasion', 'Company', 'commitments', 'blanket', 'purchase', 'orders', 'customers', 'multiple', 'year', 'deliveries', 'hardware', 'customers.', 'Our', 'Test', 'Systems', 'segment', 'designs', 'develops', 'manufactures', 'maintains', 'communications', 'weapons', 'test', 'systems', 'training', 'simulation', 'devices', 'applications.', 'In', 'Test', 'Systems', 'segment', 'Astronics', 'products', 'U.S.', 'militaries', 'manufacturers', 'communication', 'systems.', 'During', 'segment', 'sales', 'markets.', 'This', 'segment', 'revenue', 'result', 'price', 'contracts', 'percentage', 'completion', 'method', 'multiplying', 'contract', 'value', 'ratio', 'contract', 'costs', 'date', 'contract', 'costs.', 'We', 'estimates', 'usage', 'percentage-of-completion', 'contract', 'revenues.', 'We', 'contracts', 'process', 'estimates-to-completion', 'gross', 'profit', 'accordingly.', 'While', 'gross', 'profit', 'contracts', 'process', 'unforeseen', 'events', 'changes', 'circumstances', 'place', 'accounting', 'period', 'gross', 'profit', 'contracts', 'process.', 'Accordingly', 'gross', 'profit', 'completion', 'contracts', 'amounts', 'periods.', 'Sales', 'Segment', 'Geographic', 'Region', 'Major', 'Customer', 'Canadian', 'Operations', 'Note', 'Item', 'Statements', 'Supplementary', 'Data', 'report.', 'We', 'concentration', 'business', 'customers', 'Panasonic', 'Avionics', 'Corporation', 'Department', 'Defense', 'branches', 'U.S.', 'Government.', 'Sales', 'Panasonic', 'Avionics', '%', 'sales', '%', 'sales', '%', 'sales', 'Accounts', 'customer', 'December', 'respectively.', 'Sales', 'U.S.', 'Government', '%', 'sales', '%', 'sales', '%', 'sales', 'Accounts', 'customer', 'December', 'respectively.', 'Table', 'Contents', 'Strategy', 'Our', 'strategy', 'positions', 'leadership', 'chosen', 'aerospace', 'defense', 'markets', 'positions', 'amount', 'content', 'volume', 'product', 'markets', 'businesses', 'capabilities', 'leadership', 'position', 'direction.', 'Practices', 'Maintaining', 'Working', 'Capital', 'Liquidity', 'Part', 'II', 'Item', 'Management', 's', 'Discussion', 'Analysis', 'Financial', 'Condition', 'Results', 'Operations', 'Liquidity', 'section', 'report.', 'Competitive', 'Conditions', 'We', 'experience', 'competition', 'market', 'sectors', 'respect', 'performance', 'price', 'competitors', 'resources.', 'Success', 'markets', 'depends', 'product', 'innovation', 'customer', 'support', 'responsiveness', 'management.', 'We', 'technologies', 'engineering', 'support', 'markets.', 'Government', 'Contracts', 'All', 'U.S.', 'Government', 'contracts', 'subcontracts', 'U.S.', 'Government', 'customer', 'termination', 'election', 'government.', 'Since', 'January', 'acquisition', 'DME', 'revenue', 'stream', 'relies', 'spending', 'portion', 'DME', 's', 'applications.', 'Raw', 'Materials', 'Materials', 'supplies', 'components', 'sources.', 'We', 'loss', 'source', 'operations', 'long-term.', 'Seasonality', 'Our', 'business', 'seasonal.', 'Backlog', 'At', 'December', 'backlog', 'million.', 'At', 'December', 'backlog', 'million.', 'Backlog', 'Aerospace', 'segment', 'December', 'respectively.', 'Approximately', 'December', 'backlog', 'Backlog', 'Test', 'Systems', 'segment', 'December', 'Patents', 'number', 'patents.', 'While', 'aggregate', 'protection', 'patents', 'value', 'material', 'business', 'dependent', 'protection', 'patents', 'cabin', 'power', 'distribution', 'product.', 'Our', 'patents', 'patent', 'applications', 'electroluminescence', 'instrument', 'panels', 'technology', 'patent', 'cabin', 'power', 'distribution', 'technology.', 'We', 'expertise', 'techniques', 'trade', 'secret', 'laws', 'arrangements', 'rights.', 'We', 'trademark', 'protection', 'markets.', 'Table', 'Contents', 'Research', 'Development', 'Engineering', 'Activities', 'We', 'variety', 'engineering', 'design', 'activities', 'research', 'development', 'activities', 'improvement', 'application', 'technologies.', 'These', 'costs', 'cost', 'sales.', 'Research', 'development', 'engineering', 'costs']
```

Should I take the tags in context of the paragraph or should it be in context of the sentence only?

Comment: How exactly does it differ? Nouns should be nouns, regardless of the context

Comment: I'll add the 2 outputs to show the difference.

Comment: In the first example, are you calling word_tokenize on the entire list or on the split sentences? Can you show that part of the code?

Comment: I have an array of split sentences which I take one by one and feed it to word_tokenize and then I tag it with pos_tag. In the second approach I take the whole text and tokenize with the word_tokenize and then I use pos_tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer can be found on [this page](http://www.nltk.org/api/nltk.tokenize.html). It is part of the nltk documentation over at nltk.org.

First [it mentions this](http://www.nltk.org/api/nltk.tokenize.html#module-nltk.tokenize.treebank)

> The Treebank tokenizer uses regular expressions to tokenize text as in
>   Penn Treebank. This is the method that is invoked by word_tokenize().
>   **It assumes that the text has already been segmented into sentences,
>   e.g. using sent_tokenize().**

and [a bit further](http://www.nltk.org/api/nltk.tokenize.html#module-nltk.tokenize) down this

> Caution: only use word_tokenize() on individual sentences.

and

> **nltk.tokenize.word_tokenize**
>
> Return a tokenized copy of
>   text, using NLTK’s recommended word tokenizer (currently
>   TreebankWordTokenizer). **This tokenizer is designed to work on a
>   sentence at a time.**

Since it's always wise to follow official documentation, you should most definitely use your first approach, which is to first use `sent_tokenize()` and then `word_tokenize()`.

Comment: Thank you Tim. Appreciate it.